# Change htaccess to redirect to index.php in subfolder

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I change the WordPress root folder `.htaccess` file to redirect URLs with a specific subfolder to its own `index.php` and give the path data as a URL variable to the `index.php`?

```
https://example.com/subfolder/img.png
```

redirect to:

```
https://example.com/subfolder/index.php?path=img.png
```

all other redirects should work like WordPress expects them to.

Comment: I assume you mean "rewrite" as opposed to "redirect"? I assume the URL is not meant to change in the browser's address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file, before the existing WordPress directives (*before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker):

```
RewriteCond $2 !^(index\.php)?$
RewriteRule ^(subfolder)/(.+) /$1/index.php?path=$2 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive is to ensure that it doesn't try to rewrite requests for `index.php` itself (or the directory). A request for `/subfolder/` only will be served by `/subfolder/index.php` without the `path` URL parameter (by mod_dir).

Otherwise, all other requests to that subfolder (whether they map to files, directories or nothing at all) are passed to `/subfolder/index.php` in the query string.